# Image Upload s3 bucket form deployed dot net cor AWS lambda serverless app not working (broken Image)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, .net-core

when i make post request to upload image file to aws s3 bucket  form my local dot net core aws lambda serverless application it works but form my deployed application the image still uploded to s3 bucket but the image  broken (shows black empty image)

here is the code

```
    [HttpPut("PostImageFile")]
    public async Task FileImageAsync(string  Id)
    {
        var s3Client = new AmazonS3Client("*******", "*******", Amazon.RegionEndpoint.USEast1);

        try
        {
            var httpRequest = HttpContext.Request;
            //posted file
            var file = httpRequest.Form.Files[0];            

            byte[] fileBytes = new byte[file.Length];
            file.OpenReadStream().Read(fileBytes, 0, Int32.Parse(file.Length.ToString()));

            var fileName = Guid.NewGuid() + file.FileName;

            PutObjectResponse response = null;

            using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                file.CopyTo(stream);

                var request = new PutObjectRequest
                {
                    BucketName = "imageakal",
                    Key = fileName,
                    InputStream = stream,

                    ContentType = file.ContentType,
                    CannedACL = S3CannedACL.PublicReadWrite
                };

                response = await s3Client.PutObjectAsync(request);
            };
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.Write("Upload Failed: " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you have a link to the image that we can see?

Comment: yes this one when I make post request from my local server  https://imgfile1.s3.amazonaws.com/2b8c8dbd-a380-487f-8f1e-fb19dfe4de8edefault.PNG 
And this one is the same image file when I make post request from the deployed server   https://imgfile1.s3.amazonaws.com/0ec22285-4e2f-4c14-98f2-6999814797b5default.PNG
 And also I notice the size of the file increased

Comment: Cool, could you include your put code in your C# lambda

Comment: I don’t have access my pc right now and I will post the code about an hour or two

Comment: Ok i just post the code take a look at

Answer (score 1):

Without many more details, I would guess that your AWS settings could have a list of permitted/denied domains.  I would check that your AWS instance is configured to allow requests from your domain.

Answer (score 0):

Just put "multipart/form-data" at 'Binary Media Type' section in Api Gateway setting tab, and deploy it(don't forget).